# Using $priority with $push in AngularFire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularfire

I tried to push data to firebase using the following code and it works fine.

```
var firebaseObj = new Firebase("https://burning-fire-1723.firebaseio.com/Articles");
var fb = $firebase(firebaseObj);

fb.$push({
    title: "title",
    post: "post",
    emailId: "mymail@gmail.com"
}).then(function(ref) {
    console.log(ref);
}, function(error) {
    console.log("Error:", error);
});
```

Next, in order to fetch a particular record from Firebase I need to assign a priority to emailId field while pushing the data.
But I really can't figure out how to do that.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more in detail what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @DieterGoetelen I'm trying to assign a priority while pushing data to Firebase

Comment: Have you tried `fb.setWithPriority({title: 'title', post: 'post'}, 10000)`. Not sure if I understand the problem correctly.

Comment: Actually, I'm using AngularFire and `setWithPriority` is in JavaScript

Comment: You can still use the normal reference. In your example it would be `firebaseObj.setWithPriority`

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you.

```
   var user = "mymail@gmail.com";
   var firebaseObj = new Firebase("https://burning-fire-1723.firebaseio.com/Articles");
   var fb = $firebase(firebaseObj);

   fb.$push({ 
    title: title,
    post: post,
    emailId: user,
    '.priority': user
  }).then(function(ref) {
    console.log(ref); 
    $location.path('/welcome');
  }, function(error) {
    console.log("Error:", error);
  });
```

The answer came from this [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-web-app-from-scratch-using-angularjs-and-firebase-part-7--cms-23084).